# comparing Pandas dataframes by header uring regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, nsregularexpression

I have two dataframes let's call them df1 and df2, which columns with slightly different headers which I need to compare.
For example

```
df1 = pd.Dataframe('0001_baseline':[1,2,3], '0002_baseline':[1,2,3])
df1 = pd.Dataframe('0001_w2':[1,2,3], '0002_w2':[1,2,3])
```

I need to do the ratio of 0001_baseline/0001_w2.
if the names were identical I would have

```
intersec = set(df1.columns).intersection(set(df2.columns))
```

and then do the ratio according to the intersections, but the column names are different. Is there a way to perform the intersection according to column name using regex?
Or alternatively, knowing that I know how long are the characters, replace the names with a shorter version which won't cause a problem?

Comment: Do both dataframes always have the same number of columns and those columns are inorder?

Comment: nope, otherwise it would be easy... some columns do not match

Comment: Is it that the match happens for 0001 and 0002 in your example?  Like the numeric portion?  Or more complicated?  More generally - what is the matching logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by making the columns have identical elements (just the numbers and no strings). Here's how you would do it with regex:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'0001_baseline':[1,2,3], '0002_baseline':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'0001_w2':[1,2,3], '0002_w2':[1,2,3]})

namesRegex = re.compile(r'[^0-9]')

df1Col =  [namesRegex.sub('', i) for i in  df1.columns]
df2Col =  [namesRegex.sub('', i) for i in  df2.columns]
```

Now, you can convert them into integers or w/e and make the column names of your dataframes identical. I believe you can do that.